# Pentaho Kettle: load variables for database connection and set to checkbox property

Tags: sql-server, database, pentaho-spoon

I have a properties file with database connection properties. Then, I use a transformation to load variables and use it as '${VARIABLE_NAME}' in the database connection. Then problem is when I need to set a Checkbox value (with boolean value).
The data base connection is MS SqlServer (Native) with Native (JDBC), And I need to set the "Use Integrated Security" property.

[image]

Somebody knows how can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in connection with 'Use integrated Security'.
You know 'Use integrated Security' is use for windows authentication.
To do this , it is required to in place mssql-jdbc_auth dll in proper location in PDI.

Please follow the below instruction:-

1. Download MSSQL driver from [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017]
2. Copy "mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar" to your PDI lib location "..\data-integration70\lib".
3. Now the most important one is, you need to copy "mssql-jdbc_auth-8.4.1.x64.dll" to your PDI location "data-integration70\libswt\win64"
   and "mssql-jdbc_auth-8.4.1.x86.dll" to your PDI location "data-integration70\libswt\win32"
   [You will found both the dll from microsoft JDBC driver folder which one you have downloaded in step #1. And location will be "sqljdbc_8.4.1.0_enu\sqljdbc_8.4\enu\auth\x86" and "sqljdbc_8.4.1.0_enu\sqljdbc_8.4\enu\auth\x64"]
4. Now run the PDI and test your transformation.
5. Please let me know if you still found the issue.